# Throughput and Latency of a Unix Domain Socket used by a process

Tags: networking, unix-socket

My Linux machine consist of a process which is using Unix Domain Socket. How can I calculate the throughput and Latency of that domain socket. Is there any tool that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

In order to measure the throughput and speed of a unix socket you can use [socat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/socat), "multipurpose relay for bidirectional data transfer"

As per the linux man page;

> Socat is a command line based utility that establishes two
>   bidirectional byte streams and transfers data between them. Because
>   the streams can be constructed from a large set of different types of
>   data sinks and sources (see address types), and because lots of
>   address options may be applied to the streams, socat can be used for
>   many different purposes.

Simply to install using apt

Some example outputs for socat

enter link description here

Generate 1GB random file in the "shared memory" (i.e. RAM disk)

```
>dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/shm/data.dump bs=1M count=1024
Memory to disk (SSD), through UNIX socket

>socat -u -b32768 UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/unix.sock ./data.dump &
>socat -u -b32768 "SYSTEM:dd if=/dev/shm/data.dump bs=1M count=1024" UNIX:/tmp/unix.sock
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 1.96942 s, 545 MB/s
```

Memory to memory, through UNIX socket

```
>socat -u -b32768 UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/unix.sock /dev/shm/data.dump.out &
>socat -u -b32768 "SYSTEM:dd if=/dev/shm/data.dump bs=1M count=1024" UNIX:/tmp/unix.sock
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 0.927163 s, 1.2 GB/s
```

Memory to /dev/null (discard), through UNIX socket

```
>socat -u -b32768 UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/unix.sock /dev/null &
>socat -u -b32768 "SYSTEM:dd if=/dev/shm/data.dump bs=1M count=1024" UNIX:/tmp/unix.sock
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 0.720415 s, 1.5 GB/s
```

/dev/zero to /dev/null, through UNIX socket

```
>socat -u -b32768 UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/unix.sock /dev/null &
>socat -u -b32768 "SYSTEM:dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=1024" UNIX:/tmp/un    >socat -u -b32768 UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/unix.sock /dev/null &
>socat -u -b32768 "SYSTEM:dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=1024" UNIX:/tmp/unix.sock
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 0.491179 s, 2.2 GB/six.sock
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 0.491179 s, 2.2 GB/s
```

Another tool you can try out can be found here [linux-ipc-benchmarks](https://github.com/kamalmarhubi/linux-ipc-benchmarks)

A good explanation by the author of the tool is [here](http://kamalmarhubi.com/blog/2015/06/10/some-early-linux-ipc-latency-data/)

Comment: All these tools, generate data and then calculate the performance. But for my experiment, I only know about the UDS socket and the process using it. With this information, i wanted to calculate the UDS peroformance.

Comment: Data points given: processID, UDS Socket ID. Output: UDS Socket throughput & latency

Comment: are you trying to test on a pid from a program run by, and also a socket you created... or simply trying to test latency on a random pid that is using a unix socket

Comment: are you trying to test on a pid from a program run by, and also a socket you created: Yes. We can assume, it is black box and we can not change anything in the process. We just know the PID and SocketID.